# What kind of Http proxy do I need?

Tags: caching, proxy, memcached, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

So,

I have a website that is served by 12 separate application servers without any shared cache. We use a third party webservice to implement a particular functionality in the app. However, the 3rd party doesn't want us to be calling them a lot lest it breaks their site.

Hence I am thinking of keeping some kind of a proxy in between these 12 servers and the webservice so that all these go through this proxy. If the content they are requesting isnt found in the proxy, it goes over the wire, gets stuff from the 3rd party caches it and returns.

Can someone tell me what kind of proxy am I looking for? Are there some easy to setup reliable opensource projects out there that can help?

-thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a caching proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a REST web service any caching web proxy should do.

Try using varnish or squid.